# Jmeter check using if controller, for a variable has a value or not

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

in one of my steps in the Jmeter script, I'm using json extractor to read a value from a key(address) in the JSON response and store it in a variable called "TypeOfRequest." In the next step, I need to check if the "TypeOfRequest" value is null or not(There can be situations I don't find that key in the JSON response). Then I need to take a different route.

Snippet how I'm getting the TypeOfRequest from Json extractor `$.communicationMethods[:1].hTTPS.address`

So my question is, how do I check if TypeOfRequest has a value or not in the if controller?

tried using  `'${__javaScript(vars.get("TypeOfRequest") == null)}`(ref https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller and https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32969/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-null-using-a-if-controller) but unable to go through the if condition, can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesnt directly answer your question, but have you considered using a load testing tool that is fully programmable? Like Locust or k6? This sort of thing becomes almost trivial once you get rid of extractors and if-controllers and just use python/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) to see what [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are defined and inspect their values, my expectation is that you're "unable to go through the if condition" because your `TypeOfRequest` variable is not `null`, i.e. it's present but it's an empty string.

Also the referenced article suggests using [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) or [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function so I believe if you change your condition to something like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(vars.get('TypeOfRequest')),)}
```

you will be able to "go through the if condition"